# Page not found 404 on Django site?

Tags: django, view, django-urls

I'm following the tutorial on Django's site to create a simple poll app. However, Django is unable to resolve "//127.0.0.1:8000/polls" , even though I've defined the regex in mySite/urls.py. I'm doing this in a virtualenv, with the latest Django (1.7) installed.

mySite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

mySite/polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), 
)
```

mySite/polls/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

mySite/settings.py:

```
 ...
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'polls',
 ) 
  ....
 ROOT_URLCONF = 'mySite.urls'
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mySite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: ^admin/  
The current URL, polls, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: looks like you have not included `polls` package in the list of `INSTALLED_APPS` ALso, make sure you have a blank `__init__.py` in the poll package

Comment: I did, see my edits.

Comment: What if you put `urlpatterns = [url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),]` in then`polls/urls.py` instead of your version of `urlpatterns` definition?

Comment: Same error. Tried your syntax on mySite/urls.py and polls/urls.py, still same error.

Comment: Why doesn't Django see the "^polls/" regex in mySite/urls.py??

Comment: This is a guess, but your path seems to be a bit off.  Polls should be at the same level as "mySite", not inside of it.  The polls directory should be in the same folder as manage.py.  I am not sure what Django does if it doesn't recognize a URL include... but ignoring it seems likely. You can try moving the polls directory up a level, or changing the include to 'mySite.polls.urls' and see if that helps.

Comment: polls/ is at the same level as mySite/ and manage.py. The outer most folder that contains polls/ and mySite/ is also named mySite/

Comment: I have copied mySite/urls.py to mySite/mySite/urls.py and kept mySite/polls/urls.py as is. Now getting an importError at url(r'^polls/', include('mySite.polls.urls')) in mySite/mySite/urls.py No module named urls

Comment: I changed the ROOT_URLCONFIG to 'urls' and its working now

Comment: I guess depending on where you put your ROOT urls.py, you set your ROOT_URLCONFIG accordingly, if you have it in your outermost folder containing manage.py then "urls" is ok. if you have it in someother folder then you have to do "<foldername>.urls"

Comment: Does 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ work ? And have you tried 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ (including the trailing slash) ?

Comment: So the question is solved then?

Comment: Yes, it's been solved

Comment: This is weird because i just followed the tutorial and i did not have the same issue that you did. I did not have to configure any ROOT_URLCONF either. Try doing it again and see if the error replicates. Well, i think you should answer your own question otherwise the bounty will get lost @jerryh91

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I had the same problem.

It turns out I was confused because of the multiple directories named "mysite".

I wrongly  created a urls.py file in the root "mysite" directory (which contains "manage.py"), then pasted in the code from the website.

To correct it I  deleted this file, went into the mysite/mysite directory (which contains "settings.py"), modified the existing "urls.py" file, and replaced the code with the tutorial code.

In a nutshell, make sure your urls.py file is in the right directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Django really should emphasize this point in their tutorial.

Answer (score 9):

Django unable to resolve `127.0.0.1:8000/polls` because url config defined as `r'^polls/'`.

**Usual workaround:**

*mySite/urls.py:*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

*Note:*
Whenever Django encounters include(), It chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included `URLconf` for further processing.

*mySite/polls/urls.py:*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'), 
)
```

*Note:* Instead of typing that out for each entry in urlpatterns, you can use the first argument to the patterns() function to specify a prefix to apply to each view function.

**Answer If**

If you want to access `127.0.0.1:8000/polls` *Note: without trailing slash*

use view based url

```
url(r'^polls', 'polls.views.index', name='index'),
```

So now you can access `127.0.0.1:8000/polls` without trailing slash.

Comment: You have an error there, you are configuring mySite/polls/urls.py file twice.

Comment: @javidazac ah.. ! fixed now

Comment: You have mySite/polls/urls.py, so the global urls is in mySite/mySite/urls.py. NOT in mySite/urls.py.

Answer (score 5):

You're accessing to http://yourdomain.com/, and you don't have any URL defined for "/".

You have two options:

1. If you want to access to the index page of your polls application you have to enter the URL: yourdomain.com/polls
2. You can also modify you mySite/urls.py file to access from just yourdomain.com

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

   from django.contrib import admin
   urlpatterns = patterns('',

   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

   url(r'^$', include('polls.urls')),

   )
   ```

Answer (score 5):

To make the answer clear for beginners who has this issue by following the tutorial, the project root URLconf is the one in the same folder as settings.py which is:

```
 mysite/mysite/urls.py
```

Just make sure import 'include'. The code looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

So in
mysite/mysite/settings.py:

The line should be:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

You don't need create a fresh new root URLconf.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you put your ROOT urls.py, you set your ROOT_URLCONFIG accordingly, if you have it in your outermost folder containing manage.py then "urls" is ok. if you have it in someother folder then you have to do ".urls"

Credit for the answer to [jerryh91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846835/jerryh91)

For more info about how it works, check [How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Answer (score 1):

You put the urls.py folder into the outer MySite folder, you are suppose to put it in the inner one so its not mySite/urls.py, but mySite/mySite/urls.py:

ran into the same mistake when i did the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access `127.0.0.1:8000/polls` would be to redirect the browser when accessing `127.0.0.1:8000`. It is done by editing `.../mysite/mysite/urls.py` as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: How works for you? explain in the details.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: In the site1/urls.py file added "from polls import views" and in urlpatterns list added url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

Comment: Update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Page not found?**

If you get an error page here, check that you’re going to http://localhost:8000/polls/ and not http://localhost:8000/.

[image]

Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that you didn't notice that
**mysite/urls.py and polls/urls.py are two different files** and you modified polls/urls.py instead of putting mysite/urls.py in the urls.py file in ...mysite\mysite folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a *stupid* mistake. I wanted to integrate the plugin django-tinymce, and test it. So following [this](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#testing) guide, I did the step 3 and exported the variable to the path. As the server runned again, I received the not found error, showing the message:

> Using the URLconf defined in testtinymce.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order: ....

But I didn't know what exactly it was, until I remembered exporting the variable **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**

running `unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`  in terminal solved my issue. Hope that it helps someone too.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your `Mysite/urls.py`

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

and check. If you have created your project correctly, it should work. Else something like above might have happened to have more than one files so confused.

Answer (score 0):

2017-10-05_12:03 ~/mysite/mysite
$ vi urls.py
2017-10-05_12:04 ~/mysite/mysite
$ cd ../..
2017-10-05_12:04 ~
$ mv mysite SENSIBLE_NAME_DJANGO_ROOT

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and got it resolved by adding /polls after http://server:port/ and so final address in server looks like:
http://server:port/polls