# Django Tutorial Part 1 Error: URL does not match URL patterns

Tags: django

I am going throught the Django tutorial here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

I follow the instructions exactly. But when I try to go to  http://localhost:8000/polls/, I don't see the message “Hello, world. You’re at the polls index.” as expected. Instead, I get the following error:

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, polls/, didn't match any of these.

Here is my mysite/urls.py file. I am not sure why the first regex pattern in urlpatterns is not recognized.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: whats in your `polls.url` i.e. `/polls/urls.py`

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]

Comment: check this link if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716185/page-not-found-404-on-django-site

Comment: Yes that did help. Thank you! In mysite/settings.py, I changed the ROOT_URLCONF variable from 'mysite.urls' to 'urls'.

Answer (score -1):

You might have forgot `.html` extension in `views.py` while requesting the page.