# URLpattern match doesn't work as expected

Tags: django

**What I want**

I'm running the very first steps of the [Django Project tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) and there's already something i can't get right.

> The idea behind include() is to make it easy to plug-and-play URLs. Since polls are in their own URLconf (polls/urls.py), they can be placed under “/polls/”, or under “/fun_polls/”, or under “/content/polls/”, or any other path root, and the app will still work.

I built everything as needed and my 'shelves' server works fine (debug here, running on localhost).
I'm setting the urlpatterns in shelves.urls, the first of which tries to include 'bluebook.urls'.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

 urlpatterns = [
    path('bluebook/', include('bluebook.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/bluebook/, **it works fine** and loads the views.index I set up.

**What doesn't work**

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/thebluebook/, it throws a 404. It goes as far as defining regex match *not working* :

```
Using the URLconf defined in shelves.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    1. bluebook/
    2. admin/
The current path, thebluebook/, didn't match any of these.
```

It does the same with http://127.0.0.1:8000/the_bluebook/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/go/bluebook/.

**What I tried**

I haven't written much code so there's not much to join to this summary. Although the error message only mentions shelves.urls, i checked that bluebook.urls is set to accept any regex after the redirection from shelves.urls :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

I checked [Django Tutorial Part 1 Error: URL does not match URL patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452245/django-tutorial-part-1-error-url-does-not-match-url-patterns) and tried to change ROOT_URLCONF from 'shelves.urls' to 'urls', but it throws a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED instead of a 404, whatever I put after http://127.0.0.1:8000/, basically the site doesn't work anymore.

I checked out [Page not found 404 on Django site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716185/page-not-found-404-on-django-site) but my site's urls.py is in the *child folder* mysite/, not the parent mysite/.

I also tried

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bluebook/', 'bluebook.urls'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

but it doesn't work either.

Basically, all my setup looks right to me as calling the exact URLpattern works as expected. Only the regex matching doesn't seem to work.

FWIW, I'm using JetBrain's PyCharm to edit the code and setup the venv, without the plugin, but I don't see it influencing the running of Django code.

**Python-version :** Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

**Django version :** 2.0.7

**PyCharm version :** 2018.1.4

**Chrome version :** Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Why do you expect this to match with any pattern ending with bluebook?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include 'thebluebook' in your urls. you have `path('bluebook/', include('bluebook.urls')),` and `path('', views.index, name='index'),`
which means you can do http://127.0.0.1:8000/bluebook/any/thing/here/ but you can not http://127.0.0.1:8000/any/thing/here/bluebook/.

Comment: I misunderstood the explanation in the Tutorial : "route is a string that contains a URL pattern. When processing a request, Django starts at the first pattern in urlpatterns and makes its way down the list, comparing the requested URL against each pattern until it finds one that matches." because to me, `theblueblook/` matches `'bluebook/'` as it contains it. It only doesn't match `r'^bluebook/'`. What I was looking for is `r'.*bluebook/'`, but this requires `re_path()`.

Comment: Awesome, I'm happy you figured it out.