# Django Admin page won't let me delete or add users/group. urls error

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I just set up my own Django server but I am having trouble with the admin page. When I try adding or deleting users or basically whenever I send POST request from Django admin page, I am getting the following error:

```
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.changelist_view
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^register/$ [name='register']
^$
^login/$ [name='login']
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, auth/user/, didn't match any of these.
```

Normal pages work fine. I am only getting the errors on Admin page.I tried doing `python manage.py migrate`  but there are no migrations to apply. I am guessing this has to do with `urls.py` or `settings.py` files. `re_path('^admin/', admin.site.urls)` url pattern is already there, I am not sure why it is still giving the error.

Path structure:

```
-root
    -mysite
        -urls.py
        -settings.py
        -wsgi.py
        -views.py
        -forms.py
    -templates
    -static
    -passenger_wsgi.py
    -manage.py
```

**This is my urls.py file:**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^register/$', register_page, name='register'),
    re_path('^$', home_page),
    re_path('^login/$', login_page, name='login'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**And this is settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'key'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myip']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
'''
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
'''
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/referpay/rp/static'
```

Comment: ***"POST request from admin"***, What you  mean by this?

Comment: @JPG I mean when I click the submit button to delete a user or add a new user, it triggers the error

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://website/admin/auth/user/4/delete/
Raised by: django.contrib.admin.options.delete_view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716185/page-not-found-404-on-django-site

Comment: @FlavioMilan I added my folder structure. I don't see anything wrong with where the files are. :/

Comment: Are you using a custom user model?

Comment: @ChrisJones I am not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because SCRIPT_NAME was being set to a relative path and not the root of the application. I had to make the following changes to passenger_wsgi.py:

```
import imp
import os
import sys

import mysite.wsgi

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

SCRIPT_NAME = ''

class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    """
    Sets PATH_INFO from REQUEST_URI since Passenger doesn't provide it.
    """
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


application = mysite.wsgi.application
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find models.py in your application. I noticed something strange, you are putting the views and forms code of an application in the settings folder. In django, after we started a project with **django-admin.py startproject mysite**, we added a new app with the command **django-admin.py startapp app_name**. Django will create a folder with the name of the application where you will write the models, forms and views of that application.

I suggest you follow the django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but what happens if you try this?

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', register_page, name='register'),
    path('', home_page),
    path('login/', login_page, name='login'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Okay, what does is the URL when you see that error?

Comment: `Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
register/ [name='register']
login/ [name='login']
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, auth/user/, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: ahh sorry `http://www.website.a2hosted.com/admin/auth/user/` My host uses passanger_wsgi. I wonder if that has anything to do with it since it happens with POST requests only

Comment: I saw you were using passenger. That shouldn't be an issue unless there are some crazy mod to it. I don't see any models.py. Have you done a mikemigrations and a migrate?

Comment: It might have to do with not having an apps.py. Are you using django cookie cutter or some other django folder structure?

Comment: No I am not using any.  Is app.py required? I followed the tutorials, I didn't add any custom code. I tried migration but it looks like it is all up to date